# How to force NA/NULL in aggregate function if data contains NA/NULL

Tags: r, sqlite, sqldf

I am using the sqldf package a lot to aggregate dataframes based on complex conditioning. The standard behaviour of sqlite is to ignore NULL values when aggregating (e.g. calculating an average value), which is different to the standard R behaviour (which results NA if data contains NA values, unless na.rm=T is set).

Is there a way to force sqlite to have the same behaviour as R (i.e. output NA or NULL if data contains NA/NULL)?

Simple example:

```
library(sqldf)
data <- data.frame(name=c("v1","v2","v3"),value=c(5,3,NA))
mean(data$value)
> [1] NA

sqldf("SELECT avg(value) FROM data")
> avg(value)
> 1   4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below `count(value)` will equal `count(*)` if `value` has no nulls:

```
sqldf("select 
         case when count(value) = count(*) then avg(value) else null end as value
         from data")
```

This could also be written as:

```
avgNA <- function(x) {
    x <- deparse(substitute(x))
    sprintf("case when count(%s) = count(*) then avg(%s) else null end", x, x)
}
fn$sqldf("select `avgNA(value)` as value from data")
```

Comment: Great, Thanks! And special Thanks for putting it into a function!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a WHERE clause that throws away all rows if there is any NULL:

```sql
SELECT avg(value)
FROM data
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM data
                  WHERE value IS NULL)
```